# Memory leaking issue iPhone

Tags: iphone

Anyone have a idea about solve memory leak issues

i have found one memory related issue
NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3588aea0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

can anyone have a idea about how can i solve..

Thnak you

Comment: More code please. Have you modified the `main()` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably branched off a thread somewhere.  Whatever method call you and using in a different thread, put

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

At the beginning, and

```
[pool release];
```

At the end.

Answer (score 1):

This message usually occurs when you run a secondary thread without creating NSAutoreleasePool for it. On iPhone each thread requires its own `NSAutoreleasePool` object to handle autoreleased objects.